# Unable to filter out rows with NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]File loction https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aslanahmedov/walmart-sales-forecast

Im trying to filter out rows that has NaN values for weekly sales but when i did it all the rows are filtered out

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.core.interactiveshell import InteractiveShell
InteractiveShell.ast_node_interactivity = "all"

features = pd.read_csv('features.csv')
stores = pd.read_csv('stores.csv')
train = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

#concatenate datasets
df = pd.concat([features,stores,train],ignore_index=True)

df.isna().sum()

df = df[df.Weekly_Sales == 'NaN']
df.head()
```

df.head() shows that there are no data but df.isna().sum() shows that there are about 8000+ null values out of 400000+ rows. When i try to filter out df = df[df.Store == 1] it worked so im not sure why it is not the case for this

Comment: Can you post some of your df and expected results?

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing with string NaN, you can use `Series.isna()` to detect if the values are NaN. Opposite of it is `Series.notna()`

```py
df = df[df.Weekly_Sales.isna()]
```